# Trying to figure out a proper way to Snap

Tags: modeling, snapping

Well, my evaluation of potential switch from Maya to Blender continues and I got another question and this time about snapping.
On the attached picture I want to align all the green verts to the red verts. In maya this is child proof and takes a second. Well, in blender I'm stuck.

Tried all orientations including 3D Cursor and no matter what I do, I can't get it to work. Each vert normal is elsewhere and normalizing doesn't help so I can't use that. Same with edges. All I want is to be able to move the vert in line with the long edge (to the right) and snap alignment to the vert on the top.

Any ideas or tutorials where snapping is explained?
Modeling in blender (or anything for that matter) is not straightforward vs industry standards and blender's "unique personality" is starting to beat my motivation again.

[image]

Comment: double tapping G lets you slide verts along edges, if that helps. still trying to figure out what you exactly mean.

Answer (score 1):

Press . to change the center of manipulation to the cursor, center the cursor to the red vert, select the green vert, then size x 0